# CouchDB install on Linux crashing when running test suite

Tags: linux, erlang, nosql, couchdb

I've been trying to install CouchDB on my webfusion virtual server. I followed the latest instructions from the webfusion forum (see: http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?id=2355 ) and it runs (just) Futon is very sluggish and I get 502 errors. Anyway when I run the test suite it crashes and the browser hangs on the first two basic tests. Webfaction support have been great but don't have erlang experience to interpret the error logs. Can anyone help me know what might be wrong?

Comment: Not programming related, is it?

Comment: I suggest to take this question to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

Running the tests on a Webkit browser? There is a known bug. Try Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it. It didn't crash the browser this time but basics, all_docs, attachments, attachments_multipart, attachment_names, compact, config, conflicts, delayed_commits, design_docs, design_options

all the errors are:

Exception raised:
{"error":"unknown","reason":"\u000d\u000a502 Bad Gateway\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a<\h1>502 Bad Gateway\u000d\u000a

---

nginx\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a"}

except for 'compact; which also has:

Assertion failed: xhr.responseText == "This is a base64 encoded text"
Assertion failed: xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") == "text/plain"

I'm stumped but thanks Jon. Firefox helped me run the test suite.

Anybody know what these indicate?

Comment: Please update your question instead of "answering" your own question.

Further, are you using couchdb behind nginx? If yes, try using the tests against couchdb directly. If they work there, the problem should be with nginx.